I want to adjust font size of custom (foreign) fonts
Currently I am using \bangla{বাংলা লেখা} to write anything in Bangla (Bengali) language. I configured the command \bangla as \font \bangla = "Kalpurush:script=beng".
One BIG problem of this method is I can't use large/Large/Huge etc. commands to adjust the font size. The only thing works is the \scalebox{}{} command. But cannot use that to write a paragraph. Without any adjustment, the output comes out with a small font size. Ideally, I would love to have something like \documentclass[16pt]{article} as an option for this purpose.
The other problem is this method does not give me numbered lists in Bangla fonts. Same goes with page numbers. But this problem is something I can live with as long as I can have a font size adjustment.
Is there any other ways to adjust the font size of Bangla fonts. Is there any other EASIER and better way to use a Bangla font in LaTeX?
Here is a minimum working example. Using Xelatex as the compiler.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm, top=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption}

\font \bangla = "Kalpurush:script=beng"

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        The following line is written in Bangla (Bengali). \\
        {\scalebox{1.5}{\bangla{এই লাইনটি বাংলাতে লেখা}}}\\
    \end{center}
    
I would like to adjust the font size as needed by an occasion.\\
    
{\bangla{কাজের ধরনের উপর নির্ভর করে আমি অক্ষরের আকার বড় ছোট করতে চাই।}}\\
\end{document}


Use LuaLaTeX with the fontspec package to load the font. Changing page numbers might take a little extra effort.

You might define a font family:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm, top=25mm]{geometry}

\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{kalpurush}{}
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{kalpurush}{m}{n}{<->"fontkalpurush.ttf;script=beng"}{}

%\font \bangla = "Kalpurush:script=beng"

\NewDocumentCommand{\bangla}{m}{{%
  \usefont{TU}{kalpurush}{m}{n}#1%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
The following line is written in Bangla (Bengali).

\Huge\bangla{এই লাইনটি বাংলাতে লেখা}
\end{center}

I would like to adjust the font size as needed by an occasion.

\bangla{কাজের ধরনের উপর নির্ভর করে আমি অক্ষরের আকার বড় ছোট করতে চাই।}

\end{document}


But it's much easier and avoids other problems to use fontspec.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm, top=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\banglafont}{fontkalpurush.ttf}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\bangla}{\banglafont}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
The following line is written in Bangla (Bengali).

\Huge\bangla{এই লাইনটি বাংলাতে লেখা}
\end{center}
    
I would like to adjust the font size as needed by an occasion.
    
\bangla{কাজের ধরনের উপর নির্ভর করে আমি অক্ষরের আকার বড় ছোট করতে চাই।}

\end{document}

Replace fontkalpurush.ttf (which is in TeX Live) with your own font.

Here's a beginning answer for the font problem. I'm using LuaLaTeX for the engine.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm, top=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Bangla MN} % I don't have your font, so I had to use what is available to me.


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        The following line is written in Bangla (Bengali). \\
    এই লাইনটি বাংলাতে লেখা
    \end{center}
    
    I would like to adjust the font size as needed by an occasion.\\
    
কাজের ধরনের উপর নির্ভর করে আমি অক্ষরের আকার বড় ছোট করতে চাই।
    
    \Huge{কাজের ধরনের উপর নির্ভর করে আমি অক্ষরের আকার বড় ছোট করতে চাই।}
    
\end{document}


